# Making my IOS application show up an an option to import from camera

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

How can I make my IOS application appear as an option to import from the camera once a photo is selected?

EDIT: Let me be more clear. I am developing a DropBox-like application. I would like to be able to import any file pe of any type into my application from any other application. By adding "public.data" to "Document Content Type UTIs", I am able to import attachments from email, for example, into my application, but I still cannot import photos from the Camera app. My app doesn't appear as an option when trying to open the photo in other apps.

Comment: Huh? You want to be able to select an image from the camera roll and import it into your program? If so, your search term is `UIImagePickerController`.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that importing files like this is not the intended use for the Actions section of the Camera (or any other application). This is very disappointing. The kind of "open in" ability you get in apps like Mail worked very well with importing file attachments into my app, but it doesn't look like I can get that same behavior from the photo library.